# Call object on other scene C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have this problem that I want to call an object from my first scene then call that object on my second scene . I tried doing this

```
if (instance == null)
    instance = this;
else if (instance != this)
     Destroy(gameObject);

     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

and put it on the object I don't want to destroy then changed my scene on the

```
void Start(){
   SceneManagement.LoadScene("Menu",LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

But it's not there on the heirarchy

Could someone help me out

EDIT:

[image]

Now when the next scene is loaded

[image]

The object I wanted is not there anymore. It is being destroyed

Comment: Do you mean you want an object to be available in all your scenes?

Comment: @Haytam YES that's what I wanted :) .

Comment: Where do you put the first code? Because it should be working properly.

Comment: I have 2 scenes actually sir . On the first scene I put that code then when I tried to load the 2nd scene it wasn't there

Comment: In the screenshots you added, the object `Achivements` is still there?

Comment: Which object are you wanting to not be destroyed @BoonMingProg

Comment: the Achievement with bg and text childs @CoderJoe

Comment: @Haytam the Achievement with bg and text child is not there anymore which is what I wanted to stay

Comment: Try my suggestion with the `PersistentObject` script and add it to the objects that are disappearing and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: @CoderJoe there's no difference with what I did actually right because i have the code `DontDestroyOnLoad()`

Comment: If you are unwilling to attempt debugging steps then nobody here can help you @BoonMingProg

Comment: Sorry about that . Will do try sir .

Comment: @CoderJoe I have this error saying `DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Create a persistent object**

Create a preloader scene here you can place a splash screen or whatever you prefer but the important thing is loading things that should be persistent(maybe such as a network or gamemanager)

Create a script `PersistentObject.cs` and put the following code in it

```c#
private void Awake(){
  DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Put this script on any object you initialize in the preloader

## Access object from anywhere

If you want to access an object in another scene there are several ways but I will assume you do not have any specific reference to the object

So if we have a `GameManager.cs` and we created a Persistent cube in our preloader called `Cube` we can get a reference to the gameobject by saying `GameObject cube = GameObject.FindGameobjectWithName("Cube");`

Now you are able to do whatever you want by using `cube`

## Write less, Do more with singletons

Creating a singleton will also be very useful as well

```c#
public static class Singleton<T>: MonoBehavior where T: MonoBehavior{
  private static T instance;

  //Notice the lower and upper case difference here
  public static T Instance{
    get{
      if(instance == null){
        instance = GameObject.FindGameObjectOfType<T>();
      }
      return instance;
    }
  }
}
```

You can then add this to your script make accessing properties easier and reduces the amount of code you have to write

```c#
public class Cube: Singleton<Cube>{
  private string cubeName = "Jeff";

  public void ChangeCubeName(string newName){
    cubeName = newName;
  }
}
```

To access this methods of this class you could now call the singleton from anywhere in your code

Example

```c#
public class GameManager: MonoBehavior{
  private void Start(){
    cube.Instance.ChangeCubeName("Joe");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you . I just did a lil bit of expirement but yours is the closer to the answer :)